# Problema ao fazer download de uma exportação php

Tags: php, microsoft-excel, download

Boa tarde,possuo um script onde gera uma planilha excel com informações,mas após a troca do servidor passou a dar problema,antes gerava e baixava normalmente mas agora apenas salva no servidor o arquivo perfeitamente.
Porém ao invés de fazer o download do arquivo abre uma página com defeitos de codificação.
segue abaixo a parte do código que deveria trazer o download.

```
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel'); //mime type
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$filename.'"'); //tell browser what's the file name
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0'); //no cache
    readfile("download/".$filename);
    exit();
```

Answer (score -1):

Uso dessa forma e tem funcionado.

```
// Configurações header para forçar o download
header ("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header ("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D,d M YH:i:s") . " GMT");
header ("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header ("Pragma: no-cache");
header ("Content-type: application/x-msexcel");
header ("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"file.xls\"" );
header ("Content-Description: PHP Generated Data" );


// Envia o conteúdo do arquivo
echo $html;
exit;
```

Comment: Testei da sua forma fica tudo branco a página.